# Simple alternating text in Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple completed program, but i would like to add one more feature to it but I'm not sure how. I have it set up to send a message automatically every 7 seconds when a text field is selected, repeating the message of course. What I would like for it to do is alternate between two separate messages, instead just repeating the one. I would like the new program to post at an interval of 12 seconds. Can you help me? Here is my coding.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick 
SendKeys.Send(TextBox1.Text) 
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") 
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
Timer1.Enabled = True 
Timer1.Interval = (TextBox2.Text) 
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 
Timer1.Enabled = False 
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
Timer1.Enabled = False 
End Sub 
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this Code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick 
SendKeys.Send(TextBox1.Text) 
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") 
End Sub
```

TO

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If TextBox1.Text="Text1" then
             TextBox1.Text="Text2"
        Else
            TextBox1.Text="Text1"
        End If
    SendKeys.Send(TextBox1.Text)
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")  End Sub
```

As for the timer interval, that is simply set via the text box `TextBox2.Text` (if this is your code, how you you not know this?)

Also See this Question: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems